# duda sobre restar dos numeros consecutivos en una lista python

Tags: python, lista

La duda es con el segundo y tercer apartado, creo que el segundo está bien, pero el tercero a veces no entiendo de donde saca los valores que arroja, si me pueden corregir lo agradezco.

En una estación meteorológica se registra la temperatura máxima y mínima diaria durante un mes y se almacena el resultado en dos listas de valores. Diseña un programa en Pyhton en que se lean los datos por teclado y se muestre:

- La temperatura máxima media de los días del mes.
- El día con la mayor diferencia entre la temperatura máxima y la mínima.
- El mayor aumento de la temperatura mínima con respecto a la del día anterior y qué día ocurrió.

```
T_max = []
T_min = []

while len(T_max) < 3:
  valor = float(input("Introduzca una a una las temperaturas máximas de un mes: "))
  T_max.append(valor)
print(T_max)

while len(T_min) < 3:
  valor = float(input('Introduzca una a una las temperaturas mínimas de un mes: '))
   T_min.append(valor)
   


media = (sum(T_max))/(len(T_max))     # Media temperaturas máximas
print('La media aritmética de las temperaturas máximas es', media)


massima = T_max[0]-T_min[0]   
for i in range(len(T_max)):
    if T_max[i]-T_min[i] > massima:
        massima = T_max[i]-T_min[i]
        dia = i

    
print ("La mayor diferencia es:", massima, "el día:", dia)

minima = 0

for i in range(0, len(T_min)):
    
    if T_min[i] - T_min[i-1]> minima:
        minima = T_min[i] - T_min[i-1]
        

print(minima)
```

Comment: con el tercero te refieres a la mayor diferecia de minimas con respecto al dia anterior?
en tmax guarda las maximas de todo el mes, cada posicion es un dia del mes
en tmin lo mismo con las minimas
aca: "for i in range(0, len(T_min)): " lo que hace es recorrer todo la lista de minimas, restar la minima de un dia con la del dia anterior, compararla con el valor guardado , si el resultado es mayor, actualiza el valor guardado con esa resta.
T_min[ i ] - T_min[ i -1] es la resta de minimas.
si es mayor que minima, minima toma ese valor

Comment: Hazte un conjunto de prueba y muestra la salida y la salida esperada

Comment: T_min[0] - T_min[-1] no pinta bien en la primera iteracion del 3 caso

Comment: Tener en cuenta que los días van del 1-31 pero los índices de las listas van del 0-30

Comment: Que pasa si el primer día se da la máxima diferencia(caso 2) entonces no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de una de prueba para este ejercicio:

```
dias  = [ 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
T_max = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,27,27,30,31,25,20,18,10,20]
T_min = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,20,20,21,22,10, 8, 1, 0]
```

salida:

```
La media aritmética de las temperaturas máximas es 23.555555555555557
La mayor diferencia es: 20 el día: 17
10
```

salida esperada:

```
La media aritmética de las temperaturas máximas es 23.555555555555557
La mayor diferencia es: 20 el día: 18
El mayor aumento con el día anterior: 2 el día: 10
```

*Dato Curioso:

La mayor diferencia con el día anterior: 12 el día: 15